# 1 Dimensional quantum chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, tight-binding

I had a question about the transformation of the hamiltonian of a 1 dimensional quantum chain, from real space to reciprocal space. Using the given discrete fourier transforms.

$\hat{H}$ = $\sum_j$ $\frac{p^2_j}{2m}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$m$\omega_{0}^2$($x_{j+1}$ - $x_{j}$)$^{2}$.

$\hat{P_J}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$$\sum{_k}$$e^{ikja}$$\hat{P_{k}}$ and

$\hat{X_J}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}}$$\sum{_k}$$e^{-ikja}$$\hat{X_{k}}$

Is there an eligant way to get rid of the sums to get to the final result:

$\hat{H}$ = $\sum_k$ |$\frac{p^2_k}{2m}$| + $\frac{1}{2}$m$\omega_{0}^2$(2-2$\cos(ka)$)|$x_{k}^2$|.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! This is basically a question about the mathematics of discrete Fourier transforms. The transformation of the term involving the squared momentum is just [Parseval's theorem for DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem). If you seek out the derivation of Parseval's theorem, you should find that similar manipulations help you tackle the slightly more complicated term involving positional coordinates.